# How to send the details of a folder to a servlet?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am a beginner in Java and I have been asked to build a file-sharing dynamic web application. The flow of the application goes like this: `login > display folders > select a folder > display files in the folder along with an upload button`

Now, I have created the jsp pages I require, and I am also able to sign in, select a folder that redirects to another jsp page where I can upload files.

The problem I am facing is that I do not know how to get the details of the folder, such as the folder name when I click on it, into my servlet.

Here is the code for my home page

```html
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <%
        FileSharingDAO fsObj = new FileSharingDAO();
        ArrayList<FolderPOJO> folders = fsObj.getFolder();

        final int COLUMNS = 3;
        int rows = folders.size() / COLUMNS;
        int foldercounter = 0;
    %>
        <table class="grid">
        <%
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        %>
            <tr>
                <%
                    for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
                %>
                <td><a href="folder.jsp"><img src="img/small-folder.png"><br><%= folders.get(foldercounter).getFoldername()%><br></a></td>
                <%
                        foldercounter++;
                    }
                %>
            </tr>
        <% } %>     
        </table>
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
```

How do I get the folder name to a servlet so that I can fetch files from the folder based on its folder id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Instead of redirecting to `folder.jsp` using `<a href="folder.jsp">`, I called a servlet which in turn redirects to the jsp page.

Here is the updated jsp code:

```
<body>
    <jsp:include page="header.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <%
        FileSharingDAO fsObj = new FileSharingDAO();
        ArrayList<FolderPOJO> folders = fsObj.getFolder();

        final int COLUMNS = 3;
        int rows = folders.size() / COLUMNS;
        int foldercounter = 0;
    %>
        <table class="grid">
        <%
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        %>
            <tr>
                <%
                    for(int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++) {
                %>
                <td><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/HomeServlet?folderid=<%= folders.get(foldercounter).getFolderid()%>"><img src="img/small-folder.png"><br><%= folders.get(foldercounter).getFoldername()%><br></a></td>
                <%
                        foldercounter++;
                    }
                %>
            </tr>
        <% } %>     
        </table>
    <jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include>
</body>
```

Here is the `doGet()` method in the servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/folder.jsp");

        String folderid = request.getParameter("folderid");
        System.out.println("\n\nFolder id: " + folderid); // checking if folderid is fetchable or not
}
```

I am aware that the use of scriptlets is discouraged but for the time being I will complete my web app using them because I have to submit this in a few days. Will update it using JSTL later and post an update in this answer.